# How to format the text of the y Axis

Tags: ios, core-plot

The text of my y Axis is displaying with a decimal point but I need this to show as an integer value. E.g. 3000.0 should display as 3000

[image]

The yAxis interval length though is declared in the source as

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) NSDecimal majorIntervalLength;
```

How can I achieve this?

The y Axis ticks are calculated by

```
NSString *yMajorIntervalLength = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(yMaxRange / 10)] stringValue];
CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.axisLineStyle               = nil;
y.majorTickLineStyle          = nil;
y.minorTickLineStyle          = nil;
y.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromString(yMajorIntervalLength);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -setMaximumFractionDigits: and -setMinimumFractionDigits:

These configure the number of digits after the decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

`[yMajorIntervalLength stringByDeletingPathExtension]` :)

or

```
NSRange dotRange = [yMajorIntervalLength rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch];
if (dotRange.location != NSNotFound)
    test = [yMajorIntervalLength substringToIndex:dotRange.location];
```